# Fineuploader S3, OnComplete upload, uuid key

Tags: amazon-s3, fine-uploader

how to access UUID generated Key in onComplete callback?
currently only original name comes, but  generated key wanted as well

```
new FineUploaderS3({
    options: {
        request: {
            endpoint: 
            accessKey:
            params: 
        },
        signature: {
            endpoint: 
        },
        validation: {

        },
        objectProperties: { acl: "public-read" },
        key: "uuid",  
        callbacks: {

            onComplete:(id, name )=>{
                //??? Access key?
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: have you tried the [getUuid method](https://docs.fineuploader.com/branch/master/api/methods.html#getUuid)?

Answer (score 2):

Use the getUuid(id) method to get generated UUID.

```
 new FineUploaderS3({
    options: {
        objectProperties: { acl: "public-read" },
        key: "uuid",  
        callbacks: {
            onComplete:(id, name )=>{
                this.getUuid(id); //get the uuid
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm using it in Angular 5 and it seems working fine.